# How can I pass the data to database?

Tags: php, mysql

In this form I am trying to redirect the user to the given url. There I can only use get method to pass parameters. But my form data are not save in the database when I use the get method. I want to save the data at the same time in the database.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include_once 'CryptoUtils.php';
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mnumber']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $sitename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sitename']);


    $q = ("INSERT INTO template_users(Mnumber,email,fname,address,sitename) VALUES('$mobile','$email','$fname','$address','$sitename')");
    mysql_query ($q) or die("Problem with the query: $q<br>" . mysql_error());
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Ipayy </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
<center>
    <div id="login-form">
        <form action="http://api.ipayy.com/v001/c/oc/dopayment" method="get" >

            <table align="left" width="40%" border="0">
                <h1 align="left">Create Your Web Site</h1></br></br>




                <input type="hidden" name="gh" value="<?php echo $encrypted_string; ?>" />

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Mnumber" value=""  placeholder="Your Mobile Number" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="email" name="email"  value=""  placeholder="Your Email" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fname"   value=""  placeholder="Your First Name" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" value=""  placeholder="Your Address" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="sitename" value=""  placeholder="Your Site name" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit" name="btn-signup" onclick="myFunction()">Create My gomobi website</button></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>

    </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my db connection:

```
<?php
if(!mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
{
    die('oops connection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_select_db("ipay"))
{
    die('oops database selection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: Your form is submitting to a different page, it won't be able to read the data unless the page sends it back with a POST form, you'd need to use AJAX or perhaps CURL to achieve want you want.

Answer (score 1):

As you are sending requests to an external link and also want to process the same request in your own server, then either you have to use AJAX to send two requests or you have to use curl to send one request to external link. Hope the following may help.

```
<button type="button" name="btn-signup" onclick="myFunction()">Create My gomobi website</button>
```

Check above button code, I changed it to type button as I prefer you to post the form data using your myFunction() and by AJAX. Now below is the possible code for myFunction() . [Note: You must have some code already in myFunction(), which I dont know, you just keep them if needed and also add the following code to it] In case ajax form posting you need not to use method or action in your form tag.

```
function myFunction()
{
  var gh = $('input[name=gh]').val();
  var Mnumber = $('input[name=Mnumber]').val();
  var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
  var fname= $('input[name=fname]').val();
  var address= $('input[name=address]').val();
  var sitename= $('input[name=sitename]').val();
  $.get("http://api.ipayy.com/v001/c/oc/dopayment",
    { 

        gh : gh,
        Mnumber : Mnumber,
        email : email,
        fname : fname,
        address : address,
        sitename : sitename
    },
    function(data,status){
        //console.log(data);
      if(status == 'success')
       {
         //another POST or GET ajax method can be initiated with same data              
          //but differant url (the url of your php code which is inserting    data to database)Here is an example below
        $.post("storedatatodb.php",
        {
           gh : gh,
        Mnumber : Mnumber,
        email : email,
        fname : fname,
        address : address,
        sitename : sitename

        },
        function(data,status)
       {
           if(status == 'success')
             {
               // do something - redirect to some page
             }
       });
       }
    else
    {
       //show error message
       // or do nothing
    }
    });
}
```

In the above case the storedatatodb.php will be like follows

```
<?php
  include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mnumber']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$sitename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sitename']);


$q = ("INSERT INTO template_users(Mnumber,email,fname,address,sitename) VALUES('$mobile','$email','$fname','$address','$sitename')");
mysql_query ($q) or die("Problem with the query: $q<br>" . mysql_error());
?>
```

ANOTHER method is to use PHP curl .

In this case you may use any method of GET or POST in form tag and in action , use the url of the php file processing your data to insert into db. Assume the file is storedatatodb.php . The code will be like follows

```
<?php
  include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$gh = $_POST['gh'];
$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mnumber']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$sitename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sitename']);

$q = ("INSERT INTO template_users(Mnumber,email,fname,address,sitename) VALUES('$mobile','$email','$fname','$address','$sitename')");
mysql_query ($q) or die("Problem with the query: $q<br>" . mysql_error());

  //curl to send data to external URL 
  // In case of GET request
  $geturl = "http://api.ipayy.com/v001/c/oc/dopayment?gh=".$gh."&mobile=".$mobile."&email=".$email."&fname=".$fname."&address=".$address."&sitename=".$sitename;
 // Get cURL resource
  $curl = curl_init();
 // Set some options
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL => $geturl
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
 $resp = curl_exec($curl);
//Print error if any
if(curl_errno($curl))
{
echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl);
}
 // Close request to clear up some resources
 curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting data to same page 
then
change from

```
<form action="http://api.ipayy.com/v001/c/oc/dopayment" method="get" >
```

to

```
<form action="">
```

and also change from

```
<?php

include_once 'CryptoUtils.php';
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mnumber']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $sitename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sitename']);


    $q = ("INSERT INTO template_users(Mnumber,email,fname,address,sitename) VALUES('$mobile','$email','$fname','$address','$sitename')");
    mysql_query ($q) or die("Problem with the query: $q<br>" . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

to

```
<?php

include_once 'CryptoUtils.php';
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Mnumber']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['fname']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['address']);
    $sitename = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sitename']);


    $q = ("INSERT INTO template_users(Mnumber,email,fname,address,sitename) VALUES('$mobile','$email','$fname','$address','$sitename')");
    mysql_query ($q) or die("Problem with the query: $q<br>" . mysql_error());
}

?>
```